# Route is not defined after successful log in

Tags: laravel

little bit stuck with redirecting to other page after successful login for quite a long time. I believe that my understanding about sanctum auth is a bottleneck for this issue( Or maybe I am wrong ). However, after reading the docs still couldn't find the answer to my issue. Situation: I have declared few public routes and one private. I have created a user in my database and whenever I try successfully to log in it does not redirect to other page, and my credentials are 110% correct, but anyway after submit it only displays:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
> Route [/dashboard] not defined.

However, I have that route, it's protected but after sign in I assign it. Maybe I am doing in a wrong way?

welcome.blade:

```
@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <p>{{ $error }}</p>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
            <form action="{{action('App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="username" required>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
                <div class="login-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

AuthController:

```
  public function login(Request $request)
{
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('username', $fields['username'])->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $user->password)) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors('Incorrect username or password');
    } else {

        $token = $user->createToken($request->username);

        return redirect()->route('/dashboard')->with('token', $token);
    }
}
```

web.php :

```
    // Private routing
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {

    // Agents dashboard
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard.main');
    })->name('dashboard');

});
// Public routing
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
```

Dashboard -> main:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Private</h1>
@endsection
```

Comment: try return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('token', $token); removing forward slash from route name

Comment: @JohnLobo I've changed it: 
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

And my url is still at "http://127.0.0.1:8001/login", However my network tab:
https://imgur.com/a/batESjP

Comment: do you have other named route of dashboard if not then can you show dashboard.main blade file

Comment: @JohnLobo added. No I don't have any other routes which are named 'dashboard'

Comment: better check whether login reaches till redirect.if still error try clearing route cache . php artisan route:clear and php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @JohnLobo I've tried to dd($token) in AuthController - I see it, so I guess the issue is with my:

"return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('token', $token);" Maybe this is not the way how should be done the redirect to protected route? And also I've cleared to route/cache/views/configs :D

Comment: i am not sure about sanctum so lets some one help you on this.

Comment: did you changed the  public const HOME into routeServiceProvider.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `->route('/dashboard')` to `->route('dashboard')`.  This value references the name value on a route. eg:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard.main');
})->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: @JohnLobo suggested it at first. Didn't did the trick

Comment: This is my network tab: 
https://imgur.com/a/1CCaSiO
Console output:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/login 405 (Method Not Allowed) ; Why it tries to reach /login with GET? I've used it only for POST through authcontroller

Comment: clear all caches `php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan clear-compiled && composer dump-autoload`

Comment: you still need a login GET action to "show the login form"   and then a POST to handle the submit -- UPDATE, scratch that I see your welcome has the form.

Comment: Nope.. Didn't worked as well. Any ideas? :| But gonna save all the commands for clearing everything.

Comment: I will try to do the trick, I will let you know soon :)

Comment: what about <form action="{{route('login')}}" method="POST">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234916/discussion-between-henryb-and-cameron).